# How to add prefix or postfix to rename batch file?

Tags: batch-file, rename

I've created a rename batch file and it takes 3 arguments and renames files inside a folder

The batch file script is

```
@echo off&set /a cnt=1
set arg1=%1
set arg2=%2
set arg3=%3
for %%a in (%arg1%\%arg2%) do call :PROCESS "%%a"
goto :EOF
:PROCESS
rename %1 %arg3%%cnt%.*
set /a cnt+=1
```

Eg syntax is:

```
rename.bat e:\ranks\Ranks *.gif ren_

arg1: e:\ranks\Ranks
arg2: *.gif (rename only .gif files)
arg3: ren_ (prefix txt to be added to every file)
```

Now i want to get option frm the user abt whether he has to add prefix or postpix along with the txt.. How can i proceed after this?

Comment: Can you try explaining a little clearer what you want to do? I'm a bit at a loss in understanding what you want here.

Comment: I want to get an option from the user about whether to prefix or postfix some text while renaming.. For eg: if user gives the txt as 'ren' and want to prefix ,then the files should be renamed as ren_1.gif,ren_2.gif,ren_3.gif,ren_4.gif etc and if he want the txt to be postfixed then the files should be renamed as 1_ren.gif,2_ren.gif,3_ren.gif, etc..

Comment: Should that option be given on the command line as well or asked interactively (e.g. the user runs `rename.bat .\ *.txt ren` and the batch file then asks "Prefix (1) or Postfix (2)?" where the user would respond with either `1` or `2` to choose)?

Comment: @joey you understood exactly.. That's i wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to ask for user prompt, you can use `set /p`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `choice` to ask for a choice of two values:

```
echo (1) Prefix
echo (2) Postfix
choice /M "> " /N /C 12
if errorlevel 255 (
  echo User canceled
) else if errorlevel 2 (
  echo Postfix
) else if errorlevel 1 (
  echo Prefix
)
```